# Is number theory prerequisite for logic theory? Or is it the other way around?

Tags: number-theory, logic

I am learning logic 101. It is supposed to be the prerequisite for number theory and possibly for all mathematics. But the following problem arises:

Logic 101 is based on truth tables. The first step in a truth table is to fill all the possible truth value permutations of the given statements. While doing that we MUST make sure that we have not missed any certain permutation. Thus we are forced to use $2^{n}$ formula. But we are not supposed to use it right now because we have not started our number theory discussion. So what shall we do?

> My logic 101 course does mention $2^{n}$ formula but I think we shouldn't be using it right now.

Comment: Without number theory, how shall you define 2

Comment: Just as one can analyse mathematics by logic, one can also analyse logic by mathematics.

Comment: Obviously not; we do not need *number theory*. What we need is counting, as for most (every ?) human activity.

Comment: @Lord Wouldn't that be circular logic? I can't imagine how we can allow that

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA But ordinary counting is a non rigorous procedure. And shouldn't it be disallowed from rigorous treatment of mathematics by logic?

Comment: Counting (as well as language) is a prerequisite for (quite) every human activity, mathematics included. You need it to study logic, but this does not mean that you are "founding" logic on number theory.

Comment: When you verify your banck account, you check it using theorems of number theory ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I have a book "Number systems and the foundations of analysis" It starts with truth tables and logic, then constructs natural numbers, integers, rationals, reals, etc. So in the logical order of that book, we are not supposed to use $2^n$ in the very first topic on truth table. Am I right?

Comment: Also note that my book doesn't use $2^n$ formula but fills the truth table. But we must make sure we haven't missed any permutation. So we are forced to use $2^n$ formula on the very first topic. Seems circular logic to me

Comment: @Joe Checking by counting is not an issue of the theory. You as a human being might want to count the number of cases to check if all have been covered, but in that theory a proof of equivalence of two formulas might just be an enumeration of all the cases.

Comment: @Gae.S. Do you say unrigorous intuitive feelings on counting is a necessary prerequisite for learning truth table?

Comment: A "rigourous" knowledge about counting is a prerequisite for (quite) everything.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think we should replace your statement with "A knowledge about counting is a prerequisite for (quite) everything." I don't think that just the knowledge about counting has any kind of rigor. If you are counting numbers and numbers are not rigorously defined, then where is rigor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you desire is to learn a perfectly linear progression of concepts that start with logic and build up to number theory and so on... no one is going to deliver this to you. Many courses simply aren't structured this way, and some will argue that such a linearity does not even exist. I suggest you learn and accept the curriculum the way it is delivered to you, and over time, as you take more  courses and progress through your program of choice, you will get a better and better perspective of how all these ideas fit together.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that there are $2^n$ possible strings of digits $0,1$ (which I assume is the context this came up in) is a mathematical truth. "Number Theory", "Logic", etc are nothing but human classifications we came up with. Just because you are learning Logic $101$ before taking a Number Theory class does not mean that there is any circularity or that you "shouldn't be using it right now". As long as you understand why $2^n$ comes up, you shouldn't be arbitrarily forcing yourself not to use a known result for reasons like these.